# Font rendering on Dell U3818dw 38" monitor with 2014 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, font

I just got a Dell U3818dw monitor for my MBP mid 2014

When I bought the monitor I missed the fact that my old mac only supports HDMI 1.4 and is thus not able to deliver the massive 3840x1600 resolution at 60hz.

But it did automatically downgrade do 3840x1600 resolution at **30hz**, which will have to do since I am mostly working with text and my mac is up for upgrade once the 14" comes out.

Also Dell does not support Apple products so they wont help - and I can't return it (for reasons).

But the fonts are *not* smooth and I am not happy about how text is rendered.

Here you see zoomed in text on the dell (left) vs. the retina (right). Smaller text is worse, but it seems that fonts will never be smooth no matter how large I make them.
[image: dell u3818dw vs retina]

It might be hard to tell with this photo I took with my cell phone, but if you zoom in on the italics I think it is clear.
[image]

Things I tried (or didn't):

1. I don't have any issues with font rendering on my very old 24" eizo
2. I don't own another computer so I can't try the monitor on another in an easy way
3. If I go to System Prefs > General Settings. Font smoothing is enabled.
4. I played around with `defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 2` but I couldn't see any immidiate difference (in terminal window or by reloading browser)

Comment: Turning the "sharpness" down from the monitor menu from 50 to 0 mad fonts a little more fuzzy, but still not really crisp. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57963/font-smoothing-on-external-display-working-badly-rmbp?rq=1

Comment: I reset the NVRAM with no effect https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063